# Parse Subscripts and Superscripts in Nested Macros

Tags: math-mode, macros, subscripts, superscripts, parsing

### How can I parse subscripts and superscripts in nested macros?

I am trying to write two macros based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639956/parse-subscript-and-superscript-in-command):

1. underlinemacro: underline the input argument excluding subscripts and superscripts.
2. widehatmacro: put a widehat on the input argument excluding subscripts and superscripts.

I can't figure out how to write these to work for repeated or mixed applications. I'd like to be able to use `\underlinemacro{\underlinemacro{A^B_C}}` to get the same behavior as `\underline{\underline{A}}\smash{^B_C}` and likewise for `widehatmacro`. More importantly, I'd like to be able to use `\widehatmacro{\underlinemacro{A^B_C}}` to get the same behavior as `\widehat{\underline{A}}\smash{^B_C}`.

Here is an attempt at a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} 

% Example Macro ---
 
\newcommand{\ABC}{A^B_C}

% Underline Macro ---

\newcommand{\underlinemacro}[1]{   
    \expandafter\makeunderlinemacroA\expandafter{#1}}
    % Force expansion if input is a underlinemacro
    % Pass expanded output to makeunderlinemacroA

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeunderlinemacroA}{
    >{\SplitArgument{1}{_}}m}
    {\makeunderlinemacroB#1} 
    % One Input -> Two Outputs
    % A -> A x
    % A^B -> A^B x
    % A_B -> A B
    % A^B_C -> A^B C 
    % A_B^C -> A B^C
    % Pass outputs to makeunderlinemacroB

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeunderlinemacroB}{mm}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% If no value then we had A^B x or A x
        \makeunderlinemacroC{#1}{} % Pass A^B x or A x to makeunderlinemacroC 
    }{% Else, there were subscripts
        \makeunderlinemacroC{#1}{#2} % Pass A B or A^B C or A B^C to makeunderlinemacroC
    }%
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeunderlinemacroC}{
    >{\SplitArgument{1}{^}}m
    >{\SplitArgument{1}{^}}m}
    {\makeunderlinemacroD#1#2}
    % Two Input -> Four Output
    % A x -> A x x x
    % A^B x -> A B x x
    % A B -> A x B x
    % A^B C -> A B C x
    % A B^C -> A x B C
    % Pass outputs to makeunderlinemacroD

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeunderlinemacroD}{mmmm}{
    \IfValueTF{#2}{
    % If value for #2, we had A B C x or A B x x 
        \makeunderlinemacro{#1}{#3}{#2}
        % Pass to makeunderlinemacro with #3 as subscript, #2 as superscript
    }{% Else we had A x B x or A x B C or A x x x
        \makeunderlinemacro{#1}{#3}{#4}
        % Pass to makeunderlinemacro with #3 as subscript, #4 as superscript
    }%
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeunderlinemacro}{mmm}{
    \underline{#1}\smash{\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}}}

% Widehat Macro ---

\newcommand{\widehatmacro}[1]{   
    \expandafter\makewidehatmacroA\expandafter{#1}}
    % Force expansion if input is a widehatmacro
    % Pass expanded output to makewidehatmacroA

\NewDocumentCommand{\makewidehatmacroA}{
    >{\SplitArgument{1}{_}}m}
    {\makewidehatmacroB#1} 
    % One Input -> Two Outputs
    % A -> A x
    % A^B -> A^B x
    % A_B -> A B
    % A^B_C -> A^B C 
    % A_B^C -> A B^C
    % Pass outputs to makewidehatmacroB

\NewDocumentCommand{\makewidehatmacroB}{mm}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% If no value then we had A^B x or A x
        \makewidehatmacroC{#1}{} % Pass A^B x or A x to makewidehatmacroC 
    }{% Else, there were subscripts
        \makewidehatmacroC{#1}{#2} % Pass A B or A^B C or A B^C to makewidehatmacroC
    }%
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\makewidehatmacroC}{
    >{\SplitArgument{1}{^}}m
    >{\SplitArgument{1}{^}}m}
    {\makewidehatmacroD#1#2}
    % Two Input -> Four Output
    % A x -> A x x x
    % A^B x -> A B x x
    % A B -> A x B x
    % A^B C -> A B C x
    % A B^C -> A x B C
    % Pass outputs to makewidehatmacroD

\NewDocumentCommand{\makewidehatmacroD}{mmmm}{
    \IfValueTF{#2}{
    % If value for #2, we had A B C x or A B x x 
        \makewidehatmacro{#1}{#3}{#2}
        % Pass to makewidehatmacro with #3 as subscript, #2 as superscript
    }{% Else we had A x B x or A x B C or A x x x
        \makewidehatmacro{#1}{#3}{#4}
        % Pass to makewidehatmacro with #3 as subscript, #4 as superscript
    }%
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\makewidehatmacro}{mmm}{
    \widehat{#1}\smash{\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}}}

% Document ---

\begin{document}

These should produce the same output: \(\underline{A}\smash{^B_C}\)
\[  
    \underlinemacro{A^B_C} 
    \underlinemacro{\ABC} 
    \underlinemacro{\underlinemacro\ABC} 
    \underlinemacro{\underlinemacro{\underlinemacro\ABC}} 
\]

These should produce the same output: \(\widehat{A}\smash{^B_C}\)
\[ 
    \widehatmacro{A^B_C} 
    \widehatmacro{\ABC} 
    \widehatmacro{\widehatmacro\ABC} 
    \widehatmacro{\widehatmacro{\widehatmacro\ABC}} 
\]

These should produce the same output: \(\underline{\widehat{A}}\smash{^B_C}\)

\[
    \underlinemacro{\widehatmacro{A^B_C}} 
    \widehatmacro{\underlinemacro{A^B_C}} 
    \underlinemacro{\widehatmacro\ABC} 
    \widehatmacro{\underlinemacro\ABC} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very difficult, not recommend. But it's possible if you try hard enough.